# How to open parent activity with last visited content page from another activity in xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working in `xamarin.forms`. I am stuck in activity navigation in Android.

My whole application is working under one `Activity` that is `MainActivity`.
From one of my content page, I want to open Contact application with all list of contacts.

I have created one another activity and start that activity on button clicks from the Content page using Dependency service like below code.

```
var intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(ContactApplicationActivity));
Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Now `OnCreate` method of `ContactApplicationActivity` I move to Contact application. And When the user clicks on any contact `OnActivityResult` method call and open message and Email default application.

ContactApplicationActivity.cs:

```
public class ContactApplicationActivity : Activity
    {
        public object smsTask { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick,
                Android.Provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
            StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 101);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (InviteFriends.IsSMS && !InviteFriends.IsEmail)
            {
                if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    //Ensure we have data returned
                    if (data == null || data.Data == null)
                        return;
                    var addressBook = new Xamarin.Contacts.AddressBook(this);
                    addressBook.PreferContactAggregation = false;

                    //Load the contact via the android contact id in the last segment of the Uri returned by the  android contact picker
                    var contact = addressBook.Load(data.Data.LastPathSegment);

                    //Use linq to find a mobile number
                    var mobile = (from p in contact.Phones
                                  where p.Type == Xamarin.Contacts.PhoneType.Mobile
                                  select p.Number).FirstOrDefault();

                    //See if the contact has a mobile number
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobile))
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "No Mobile Number for contact!",
                            ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger.CanSendSms)
                        {
                            CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger.SendSms(mobile, "My Message");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (!InviteFriends.IsSMS && InviteFriends.IsEmail)
            {
                //Ensure we have data returned
                if (data == null || data.Data == null)
                    return;
                var addressBook = new Xamarin.Contacts.AddressBook(this);
                addressBook.PreferContactAggregation = false;

                //Load the contact via the android contact id in the last segment of the Uri returned by the android contact picker
                var contact = addressBook.Load(data.Data.LastPathSegment);

                //Use linq to find a mobile number
                var emailid = (from p in contact.Emails
                               where p.Type == Xamarin.Contacts.EmailType.Home
                               select p.Address).FirstOrDefault();

                //See if the contact has a mobile number
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailid))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "No Email for contact!",
                        ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var email = BuildSampleEmail(emailid, true).Build();
                    if (CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
                    {
                        CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        public static EmailMessageBuilder BuildSampleEmail(string ToEmailId, bool sendAsHtml = false)
        {
            //var builder = new EmailMessageBuilder()
            //    .To(ToEmailId)
            //    .Cc("cc.plugins@xamarin.com")
            //    .Bcc(new[] { "bcc1.plugins@xamarin.com", "bcc2.plugins@xamarin.com" })
            //    .Subject("eRecall App");

            var builder = new EmailMessageBuilder()
                .To(ToEmailId)
                .Subject("ABC");

            if (sendAsHtml)
                builder.BodyAsHtml("<b>My Message </b>");

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine. But the problem is when Contact application is open from `ContactApplicationActivity` Activity. `MainActivity` is in the background. When I try to open My original application from Background mode. It opens with a blank screen with Title `ContactApplicationActivity`. And When I press back button `MainActivity` with my last content page is open.

I want to open Last content page of my `MainActivity` without any blank screen

Is it possible to solve it using `activity flag`?

Comment: Removing that + the excessive bolding, maybe then someone cares to actually help. Btw. "do the needful" doesn't really mean anything for us outside of India.

Comment: Did you tried to add code `Forms.Context.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));` in the `OnResume` of your `ContactApplicationActivity`?

Comment: Yes, every time it goes to OnResume, not only application resume. So call  ContactApplicationActivity in OnCreate and then OnResume call so move back to MainActivity.

Comment: Have you find any solution?